# How to pop through fragment stack in NavController without loosing "parent" state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I open some main fragment `FragA`, which then can open other fragments, that are added to the stack, but when I press back I show a `DialogC`, which should clear the stack and get me back to `FragA`, without loosing it's state, restore it from stack, rather then creating it - to recreate it I'll have to pass some arg through the whole stack.
I tried some configs with `popUpTo` in different places, and also used `findNacController.popUpTo(with/out_aruments)` or `findNavController.navigate(R.id.action_dialog_c_to_frag_a)` without `destination` defined in action, but pop can't find action in stack, navigate wants to recrete fragment when destination is defined, withou it cannot find pop action in stack (`I/NavController: Ignoring popBackStack to destination frag_a as it was not found on the current back stack`)

This is sample of my `nav_graph`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/asdf"
            android:name="SomeNaviFragment">
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_asdf_to_frag_a"
                    app:destination="@id/frag_A" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_A"
            android:name="FragA">
        <argument
            android:name="some_id"
            app:argType="integer" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_frag_a_to_frag_b"
            app:destination="@id/frag_B" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_B"
            android:name="FragB">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_frag_b_to_dialog_frag_c"
            app:destination="@id/DialogFragC"/>
        </fragment>
        <dialog
            android:id="@+id/DialogFragC"
            android:name="DialogC">
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_dialog_c_to_frag_a"
                    app:popUpTo="@id/frag_a"
                    app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
        </dialog>
</navigation>
```

In short - I wan't to go deeper from `FragA` through some fragments, but when the `DialogC` shows up in some point, I want to get back to `FragA`, to it's initial state. Is it possible to achive it without passing the creation arguments for `FragA`?
Some solution already tried, like: [Navigate Back with Navigation Component](https://medium.com/@programmerr47/navigate-back-with-navigation-component-6cec37ba6964) with it's linked resources, but this didn't help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the article in your post to make this https://github.com/yoobi/backNavigation I hope it helps.

EDIT: you're looking for a combination of this and the article then.

- The `popUpTo` attribute of an action "pops up" the back stack to a given destination before navigating. (Destinations are removed from the back stack.)
- If the `popUpToInclusive` attribute is false or is not set, `popUpTo` removes destinations up to the specified destination, but leaves the specified destination in the back stack.
- If `popUpToInclusive` is set to true, the `popUpTo` attribute removes all destinations up to and including the given destination from the back stack.
- If `popUpToInclusive` is true and `popUpTo` is set to the app's starting location, the action removes all app destinations from the back stack. The Back button takes the user all the way out of the app.

You can also check the count of your backstack with : `parentFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount`

Comment: me too, thats is why I posted it there, so I won't get duplicated hints - this works, that's true, but not in such case - I want to pop all fragments created by navigation when an action is performed on DialogC, and that example doesn't help with that

Comment: I've updated my post with an explication on how `popUpToInclusive` and `popUpTo` works.

Comment: Now, the explanaition with `popUp`s shows where I had a misconfig in my code - I had too much `inclusive`s, which broke the navigation. Thanks for the update.